# Jackson: Deserializing xml attribute where the JsonProperty doesn't match the bean name

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I have an xml blob like

```
<geocode id="1" match_count="1"/>
```

and a bean, like

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "id", "match_count" })
public class GeocodeTypeImpl implements GeocodeType {

    private String m_id;
    private String m_matchCount;

    @Override
    @JsonProperty("id")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    public String getId() {
        return m_id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(String id) {
        m_id = id;
    }

    @Override
    @JsonProperty("match_count")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    public String getMatchCount() {
        return m_matchCount;
    }

    @Override
    public void setMatchCount(String matchCount) {
        m_matchCount = matchCount;
    }
}
```

When i deserialize it, i get the error:

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "match_count" (class com.acme.cegbu.geocoder.acmeresponse.impl.GeocodeTypeImpl), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "id", "match_count"])

When i set a breakpoint in Jackson 2.9.6's

```
BeanPropertyMap.find(String) line 533
```

I see the call for "id" and it finds it fine.

But the call for "match_count" fails, and when i look in the variable

_hashArea of BeanPropertyMap i see

```
[null, null, null, null, matchCount, [property 'matchCount'], id, [property 'id'], null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: did you try to specify local name in the xml annotation? `@JacksonXmlProperty(localName="match_count", isAttribute = true)`

Comment: ah that seemed to work. Not sure i understand the purpose of @JsonProperty then. thanks!